# Return an average of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Looking to receive an array and take and return the average. If it is an empty string return 0.
This is the code I have so far.

```
For some reason I am getting NaN when entered an empty array.



function calculateAverage(numbers) {
  if ((numbers = [])) return 0;
  let total = 0;
  for (let num of numbers) {
    total += num;
  }
  let result = total / numbers.length;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: `numbers = []` makes no sense. Why did you put it there?

Comment: `if ((numbers = [])) return 0;` => `if (numbers.length == 0) return 0;`